# Using forloop to populate brackets

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I want to learn to use for loop to populate brackets such as the following:-
$max starts at 8 and can be maximum of 512. I only know very basics of forloop, not too well to form the below brackets.. can someone help me on this and explain how they done it.
Each goes into simple pattern/sequence.

I appreciate it very much.

```
$max = 8;

if($max == 8)

[[0, 0], [0, 0]],   
[[0, 0], [0, 0]], 
[[0, 0]],
[[0, 0]]

if($max == 16)

[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0]],
[[0,0]]

if($max == 32)

[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0], [0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0], [0,0]],
[[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
```

etc until 512.
Thanks

Comment: You've got two `$max == 32`s there..

Comment: Is `$max` always a multiple of 4? Also, you can have a good reading about php for loops here - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php What you need here is a `nested for loop`.

Comment: ops sorry $max is always doubled.. 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512.

Answer (score 0):

So basically this would do:

```
$max = 8;
$arrays = array();
for($i = $max/4; $i >= 1; $i/=2) {
  $array = array_fill(0, $i, array(0,0));
  $arrays[] = $array;
  $arrays[] = $array;
}
```

And as a string:

```
$max = 8;
$arrays = array();
for($i = $max/4; $i >= 1; $i/=2) {
  $array = array_fill(0, $i, '[0,0]');
  $array = '['.implode(', ', $array).']';
  $arrays[] = $array;
  $arrays[] = $array;
}
$arrays = implode(",\n", $arrays);
```

Comment: Thanks but would you be able to show how to use $arrays[] to populate a string containing the brackets I have mentioned, if that makes sense?

Comment: You want the `[[0, 0], [0, 0]],   
[[0, 0], [0, 0]], 
[[0, 0]],
[[0, 0]]` as a literal string? Or am i misreading you here?

Comment: Yes just as a literal string.