# Loop to return next match number

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, for-loop, brackets

I am trying to form a loop in returning the next match number in a tournament tree.
I managed to do the upper bracket but the lower bracket I am having trouble.

You can take a look at this pic to know exackly what I am looking for:
http://s21.postimg.org/3ryr344br/bracket.png (which is an example if max = 32)

So for example in the image where it shows 32, the next match number should return 40.
Match number 44 or 45 should return 50.

Any help is appreciated.
Many thanks

## If max = 8

8 = 10 = 1st round starts

9 = 11

10 = 12 = 2nd round starts

11 = 12

12 = 13 = to final round

## If max = 16

16 = 20 = 1st round starts

17 = 21

18 = 22

19 = 23

20 = 24 = 2nd round starts

21 = 24

22 = 25

23 = 25

24 = 26 = 3rd round starts

25 = 27

26 = 28 = 4th round starts

27 = 28

28 = 29 = to final round

## If max = 32

32 = 40 = 1st round starts

33 = 41

34 = 42

35 = 43

36 = 44

37 = 45

38 = 46

39 = 47

40 = 48 = 2nd round starts

41 = 48

42 = 49

43 = 49

44 = 50

45 = 50

46 = 51

47 = 51

48 = 52 = 3rd round starts

49 = 53

50 = 54

51 = 55

52 = 56 = 4th round starts

53 = 56

54 = 57

55 = 57

56 = 58 = 5th round starts

57 = 59

58 = 60 = 6th round starts

59 = 60

60 = 61 = to final round

## max can be up to 512

Comment: Read the question 2 times and image, but didn't understand a thing. Is it just me?

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957114/using-array-fill, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449679/using-forloop-to-populate-brackets, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343955/working-around-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

I've made something similar some time ago, but was using sql table to hold the data. Maybe this code will help you a little bit:

```
    $participants = 32;
    $games = participantsToGames($participants);
    $rounds = log($participants, 2);

    echo "#Participants: $participants; games: $games; rounds: $rounds <br />";

    echo "TRUNCATE TABLE `participants`;<br />";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $participants; $i++){
        echo "INSERT INTO `participants` (`title`) VALUES ('Driver $i');<br />";
    }

    echo "TRUNCATE TABLE `games`;<br />";
    $participantsLeft = $participants;
    $gameNumber = 1;
    $gamesAfterLastRound = 1;

    for($round = 1; $round <= $rounds; $round++){
        $nrOfGames = $participantsLeft / 2;

        for($gameNrThisRound = 1; $gameNrThisRound <= $nrOfGames; $gameNrThisRound++, $gameNumber++){
            $nextGame = ($participantsLeft == 2) 
                ? 0 
                : $gamesAfterLastRound -1 + ceil($nrOfGames + $gameNrThisRound / 2);

            $nextGamePosition = ($gamesAfterLastRound -1 + ($nrOfGames + $gameNrThisRound / 2) == $nextGame) 
            ? 'b'
            : 'a'; 

            if ($round == 1){
                $a = ($participantsLeft * $gameNrThisRound / $nrOfGames) - 1;
                $b = $a + 1;
                echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `games` (`participant_a`, `participant_b`, `round`, `game_number`, `next_game`, `next_game_position`) "
                        ."VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$round', '$gameNumber', '$nextGame', '$nextGamePosition');<br />";
            }elseif ($round == $rounds){
                echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `games` (`round`, `game_number`, `next_game`, `next_game_position`) "
                        ."VALUES ('$round', '$gameNumber', '0', '0');<br />";
                $gameNumber++;
                echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `games` (`round`, `game_number`, `next_game`, `next_game_position`) "
                        ."VALUES ('$round', '$gameNumber', '0', '0');<br />";
            }else{
                echo $sql = "INSERT INTO `games` (`round`, `game_number`, `next_game`, `next_game_position`) "
                        ."VALUES ('$round', '$gameNumber', '$nextGame', '$nextGamePosition');<br />";
            }


        }
        echo '#<br />';
        $gamesAfterLastRound = $gameNumber;
        $participantsLeft /= 2;

    }
    echo "UPDATE `games` SET `next_game` = 32 WHERE `next_game`=31";


    function participantsToGames($participants){
        if ($participants == 2) return 1;
        return participantsToGames($participants / 2) + ($participants / 2);
    }






    /*
     * 
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `games` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `participant_a` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `participant_b` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `winner` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `round` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `game_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `next_game` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `next_game_position` enum('a','b') NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participants` (
      `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
*/
```

Jus add those two tables to a database and then execute SQL queries returned by this script. You will have one table for participant and other for games slots.